# Different sensors values across multiple android systems on the same smartphone

Tags: android, kernel, accelerometer, sensors, rom

It is possible that across multiple android systems on the same smartphone sensors register different value? I researched a luxometer in smartphone with same the  artificial light which registered values vary around 200-600ln. What can cause such differences?
The problem appear in more than one smartphone.

Comment: Can you show any code how you get sensor values? I don't know much about sensors, but you need to calibrate most of them to a common base value. Who is calibrating the sensors in the smarphones?

Comment: This chart present registered values of luxometer across multiple android systems [link](https://ibb.co/gpAhRQ)